# Prove that $\sup[0,1] =1$

Tags: real-analysis

Alongside the question in the title, does it matter if the question is $(0,1)$ or $[0,1)$?

I know that it satisfies the first condition, $1$ is an upper bound but I am not sure where to go from there.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** To show that the supremum of $[0,1]$ is $1$, you need to show two things: 1) that it is an upper bound and 2) that there is no lower upper bound.

You say you've already proved (1); so, it comes down to (2).  Can you show that if $x<1$, then $x$ is not an upper bound on $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

A number $a$ is supremum of a set $A$ if

1. $a\geq x$, for all $x\in A$
2. If $b\geq x$, for all $x\in A$, then $a\leq b$.

By definition of supremum, $1= \sup(0,1)=\sup[0,1)=\sup[0,1]$.